# Triggering event with react-ga returns "Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined"

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, react-ga

I get this error:

> Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined

...when trying to trigger an event like this

```
ReactGA.event({
  category: 'Navigation',
  action: 'Clicked main CTA',
})
```

**What does that mean?**

I have initialised it like this:

```
ReactGA.initialize(process.env.REACT_APP_UA_ID, {
  debug: true,
})
```

And pageviews work:

```
ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search)
```

Answer (score -1):

Prior to firing `ReactGA.pageview()`, try firing `ReactGA.set()`. Initializing GA when your app loads should look along the lines of this;

```
ReactGA.initialize({ 'ID', {
  debug: true,
  }
})

ReactGA.set({ page: window.location.pathname + window.location.search });
ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
```